# Can't access the contents of a sub folder inside _post folder

Tags: jekyll, liquid

- MyBlogContent is a sub folder containing .md files.
- Works fine when the .md files are placed in the _post folder.
- Used the front matter as "category: MyBlogContent" in the .md file.

How I try to get all posts in MyBlogContent category :

```
 {% for post in site.category.MyBlogContent %}
    <li>
        <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    </li>
 {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`site.category` key doesn't exist. You must look in `site.categories`, like this :

```
{% for post in site.categories.MyBlogContent %}
```